# How do I write a conditional xpath select for specific nodes?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xpath, ecma

So I have a userscript added on chrome, autopagerizer.

currently I'm using

```html
//div[@class=\'entry-content\']/p[contains(.,\'chapter\') or contains(.,\'Chapter\') or preceding-sibling::p[contains(.,\'Chapter\')] and (following-sibling::p[contains(.,\'Translator Ramblings\')] or following-sibling::p[contains(.,\'Translating Ramblings\')] or following-sibling::p[contains(.,\'Ramblings\')] or following-sibling::p[starts-with(.,\'Translator\')] or following-sibling::p[starts-with(.,\'Translating\')])]
```

I want a conditional argument where when the above code doesn't resolve anything, it would select

```html
//h3[contains(.,\'Share this\')]
```

Instead. I Only want the h3 to be selected when that's the case. I can't figure out how to write this in xpath, I've looked up the other related questions and they don't resolve this issue. If I can't solve this with xpath, how would I solve this with javascript? I'm using grease monkey on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the pattern to achieve what you explained using pure XPath 1.0 could be as follows :

```
expression1 | expression2[not(expression1)]
```

So, in the context of your question :

- expression1 (truncated): `//div[@class=\'entry-content\']/p[...]`
- expression2: `//h3[contains(.,\'Share this\')]`
- solution:

  ```
  //div[@class=\'entry-content\']/p[...]  | 
    //h3[contains(.,\'Share this\')]
        [not(//div[@class=\'entry-content\']/p[...])]
  ```

This could be much cleaner if implemented with help of Javascript. Simply execute expression1, and if the result is of length 0 then execute expression2.

Comment: Thank you :)

At first I tried copying an XOR example, but that wasn't exactly what I was looking for; especially when the 2nd expression would always be true. I know that I could edit the javascript, and add another field. However I felt that just editing the xpath would be fine. If I end with more complicated xpath expressions in the future I might consider rewriting the entire grease monkey plugin lol. The primary reason for keeping 100% xpath is because I have an xpath checker (called xpath helper, but it's a checker?) and would make debugging easy to verify where problems are occurring.